# Stations with orbit making move too fast

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have to land on HARTSFIELD PLANT from POTRITI for my 1st mission but the plant is moving really fast due to potriti's orbit, and i do not have any gravity and i can not use my landing pad. 
Do you have an exeplenation or even a solution?

PS:it is my first day playing the game.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask. Are you having trouble getting out of SuperCruise to get into the station's gravity?

Comment: probably, oh yes i get it now thanks to your question, we have to make a "little space jump" to get out of space to get near the stations even if we are close in the space but i do not know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

As you fly to the station in Supercruise, wait until your destination is about 6 seconds left before impact. Then pull your throttle back to the blue region. Once you do so, the game will automatically slow you down to reach the target at a safe speed.

**NOTE:** This does not mean you will land in 6 seconds. Once you have more experience there are more aggressive (and fun) ways to approach faster, however these risk overshooting your target and having to do it all over again.

I've found the following YouTube videos helpful:

- [Elite Dangerous Tutorial Fast Supercruise Travel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LA7Iy5vQm7A)
- [Elite Dangerous Tutorial Avoid Pirate Interdiction and Supercruise
  Quickly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nC3KmSF85Q)